# Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error - pod CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, rancher, ingress-controller

I have a k8s cluster with 6 nodes and ingress controllers spawned over all of them. But 3 of 6 pods are not working properly.

```bash
kubectl -n ingress-nginx get pods
NAME                                   READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-mjxvv   0/1     Completed          0          147d
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-jz84x    0/1     Completed          0          147d
nginx-ingress-controller-4xrsq         1/1     Running            0          240d
nginx-ingress-controller-dkwst         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8          18m
nginx-ingress-controller-ft7jq         1/1     Running            0          240d
nginx-ingress-controller-hwrr9         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   12         37m
nginx-ingress-controller-rk4b2         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8          18m
nginx-ingress-controller-tg6pm         1/1     Running            1          249d
```

Log output isn't helping because the pod not even start

```bash
kubectl -n ingress-nginx logs  nginx-ingress-controller-dkwst
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       nginx-0.43.0-rancher1
  Build:         git-7eabf144d
  Repository:    https://github.com/rancher/ingress-nginx.git
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.6

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
unknown flag: --controller-class
Usage of :

unknown flag: --controller-class
      --add_dir_header                          If true, adds the file directory to the header of the log messages
      --alsologtostderr                         log to standard error as well as files
      --annotations-prefix string               Prefix of the Ingress annotations specific to the NGINX controller. (default "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io")
      --apiserver-host string                   Address of the Kubernetes API server.
                                                Takes the form "protocol://address:port". If not specified, it is assumed the
                                                program runs inside a Kubernetes cluster and local discovery is attempted.
      --certificate-authority string            Path to a cert file for the certificate authority. This certificate is used
                                                only when the flag --apiserver-host is specified.
      --configmap string                        Name of the ConfigMap containing custom global configurations for the controller.
      --default-backend-service string          Service used to serve HTTP requests not matching any known server name (catch-all).
                                                Takes the form "namespace/name". The controller configures NGINX to forward
                                                requests to the first port of this Service.
      --default-server-port int                 Port to use for exposing the default server (catch-all). (default 8181)
      --default-ssl-certificate string          Secret containing a SSL certificate to be used by the default HTTPS server (catch-all).
                                                Takes the form "namespace/name".
      --disable-catch-all                       Disable support for catch-all Ingresses
      --election-id string                      Election id to use for Ingress status updates. (default "ingress-controller-leader")
      --enable-metrics                          Enables the collection of NGINX metrics (default true)
      --enable-ssl-chain-completion             Autocomplete SSL certificate chains with missing intermediate CA certificates.
                                                Certificates uploaded to Kubernetes must have the "Authority Information Access" X.509 v3
                                                extension for this to succeed.
      --enable-ssl-passthrough                  Enable SSL Passthrough.
      --health-check-path string                URL path of the health check endpoint.
                                                Configured inside the NGINX status server. All requests received on the port
                                                defined by the healthz-port parameter are forwarded internally to this path. (default "/healthz")
      --health-check-timeout int                Time limit, in seconds, for a probe to health-check-path to succeed. (default 10)
      --healthz-port int                        Port to use for the healthz endpoint. (default 10254)
      --http-port int                           Port to use for servicing HTTP traffic. (default 80)
      --https-port int                          Port to use for servicing HTTPS traffic. (default 443)
      --ingress-class string                    Name of the ingress class this controller satisfies.
                                                The class of an Ingress object is set using the field IngressClassName in Kubernetes clusters version v1.18.0 or higher or the annotation "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" (deprecated).
                                                If this parameter is not set, or set to the default value of "nginx", it will handle ingresses with either an empty or "nginx" class name.
      --kubeconfig string                       Path to a kubeconfig file containing authorization and API server information.
      --log_backtrace_at traceLocation          when logging hits line file:N, emit a stack trace (default :0)
      --log_dir string                          If non-empty, write log files in this directory
      --log_file string                         If non-empty, use this log file
      --log_file_max_size uint                  Defines the maximum size a log file can grow to. Unit is megabytes. If the value is 0, the maximum file size is unlimited. (default 1800)
      --logtostderr                             log to standard error instead of files (default true)
      --maxmind-edition-ids string              Maxmind edition ids to download GeoLite2 Databases. (default "GeoLite2-City,GeoLite2-ASN")
      --maxmind-license-key string              Maxmind license key to download GeoLite2 Databases.
                                                https://blog.maxmind.com/2019/12/18/significant-changes-to-accessing-and-using-geolite2-databases
      --maxmind-mirror string                   Maxmind mirror url (example: http://geoip.local/databases
      --metrics-per-host                        Export metrics per-host (default true)
      --monitor-max-batch-size int              Max batch size of NGINX metrics (default 10000)
      --one_output                              If true, only write logs to their native severity level (vs also writing to each lower severity level
      --profiler-port int                       Port to use for expose the ingress controller Go profiler when it is enabled. (default 10245)
      --profiling                               Enable profiling via web interface host:port/debug/pprof/ (default true)
      --publish-service string                  Service fronting the Ingress controller.
                                                Takes the form "namespace/name". When used together with update-status, the
                                                controller mirrors the address of this service's endpoints to the load-balancer
                                                status of all Ingress objects it satisfies.
      --publish-status-address string           Customized address to set as the load-balancer status of Ingress objects this controller satisfies.
                                                Requires the update-status parameter.
      --report-node-internal-ip-address         Set the load-balancer status of Ingress objects to internal Node addresses instead of external.
                                                Requires the update-status parameter.
      --skip_headers                            If true, avoid header prefixes in the log messages
      --skip_log_headers                        If true, avoid headers when opening log files
      --ssl-passthrough-proxy-port int          Port to use internally for SSL Passthrough. (default 442)
      --status-port int                         Port to use for the lua HTTP endpoint configuration. (default 10246)
      --status-update-interval int              Time interval in seconds in which the status should check if an update is required. Default is 60 seconds (default 60)
      --stderrthreshold severity                logs at or above this threshold go to stderr (default 2)
      --stream-port int                         Port to use for the lua TCP/UDP endpoint configuration. (default 10247)
      --sync-period duration                    Period at which the controller forces the repopulation of its local object stores. Disabled by default.
      --sync-rate-limit float32                 Define the sync frequency upper limit (default 0.3)
      --tcp-services-configmap string           Name of the ConfigMap containing the definition of the TCP services to expose.
                                                The key in the map indicates the external port to be used. The value is a
                                                reference to a Service in the form "namespace/name:port", where "port" can
                                                either be a port number or name. TCP ports 80 and 443 are reserved by the
                                                controller for servicing HTTP traffic.
      --udp-services-configmap string           Name of the ConfigMap containing the definition of the UDP services to expose.
                                                The key in the map indicates the external port to be used. The value is a
                                                reference to a Service in the form "namespace/name:port", where "port" can
                                                either be a port name or number.
      --update-status                           Update the load-balancer status of Ingress objects this controller satisfies.
                                                Requires setting the publish-service parameter to a valid Service reference. (default true)
      --update-status-on-shutdown               Update the load-balancer status of Ingress objects when the controller shuts down.
                                                Requires the update-status parameter. (default true)
  -v, --v Level                                 number for the log level verbosity
      --validating-webhook string               The address to start an admission controller on to validate incoming ingresses.
                                                Takes the form "<host>:port". If not provided, no admission controller is started.
      --validating-webhook-certificate string   The path of the validating webhook certificate PEM.
      --validating-webhook-key string           The path of the validating webhook key PEM.
      --version                                 Show release information about the NGINX Ingress controller and exit.
      --vmodule moduleSpec                      comma-separated list of pattern=N settings for file-filtered logging
      --watch-namespace string                  Namespace the controller watches for updates to Kubernetes objects.
                                                This includes Ingresses, Services and all configuration resources. All
                                                namespaces are watched if this parameter is left empty.
```

I've been searching through all day and most of the answers are related to exit code `255`, in this case the exit code is `2`

```bash
kubectl -n ingress-nginx describe pod nginx-ingress-controller-hwrr9
Name:         nginx-ingress-controller-hwrr9
Namespace:    ingress-nginx
Priority:     0
Node:         leon/172.30.36.17
Start Time:   Fri, 14 Oct 2022 14:05:58 -0300
Labels:       app=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
              controller-revision-hash=6d48c5f9b4
              pod-template-generation=2
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.42.1.154/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.42.1.154/32
Status:       Running
IP:           10.42.1.154
IPs:
  IP:           10.42.1.154
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/nginx-ingress-controller
Containers:
  controller:
    Container ID:  docker://b0e5c09c46c88af20d4cf88ef9d5061a3ded5121999e1a2614e034d125659fb2
    Image:         rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-0.43.0-rancher1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://rancher/nginx-ingress-controller@sha256:677fb1a51ceb290f503fd44e6e27cf020813cf36d6822eea0ec8edff73002595
    Ports:         80/TCP, 443/TCP, 8443/TCP
    Host Ports:    80/TCP, 443/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      /nginx-ingress-controller
      --election-id=ingress-controller-leader-nginx
      --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
      --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
      --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
      --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
      --validating-webhook=:8443
      --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
      --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Fri, 14 Oct 2022 14:27:32 -0300
      Finished:     Fri, 14 Oct 2022 14:27:32 -0300
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  9
    Liveness:       http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:      http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:       nginx-ingress-controller-hwrr9 (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:  ingress-nginx (v1:metadata.namespace)
      LD_PRELOAD:     /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
    Mounts:
      /usr/local/certificates/ from webhook-cert (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from ingress-nginx-token-sfjvg (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  webhook-cert:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  ingress-nginx-admission
    Optional:    false
  ingress-nginx-token-sfjvg:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  ingress-nginx-token-sfjvg
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     :NoExecute op=Exists
                 :NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule op=Exists
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               21m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned ingress-nginx/nginx-ingress-controller-hwrr9 to leon
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  21m                   kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "6160500e9c31a4e4cad778e1bd65d0d4f7140a274ad7846c9e288db09bedde5a" network for pod "nginx-ingress-controller-hwrr9": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-ingress-controller-hwrr9_ingress-nginx" network: unable to create chain CNI-HOSTPORT-SETMARK: failed to list iptables chains: running [/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -S --wait]: exit status -1:
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  21m                   kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "c3ef2e5f7f3bd6b4396b3c4dbc07b7427ff6fe4c49454c828bb0f15e87850a14" network for pod "nginx-ingress-controller-hwrr9": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-ingress-controller-hwrr9_ingress-nginx" network: unable to create chain CNI-HOSTPORT-SETMARK: failed to list iptables chains: running [/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -S --wait]: exit status -1:
  Normal   SandboxChanged          21m (x3 over 21m)     kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  21m                   kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "d446cfcbdc7aeaf57a582d85528b79254b2cd31fcb8c8ea4130c4ec190dc987a" network for pod "nginx-ingress-controller-hwrr9": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-ingress-controller-hwrr9_ingress-nginx" network: unable to create chain CNI-HOSTPORT-SETMARK: failed to list iptables chains: running [/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -S --wait]: exit status -1:
  Normal   Pulled                  20m (x4 over 21m)     kubelet            Container image "rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-0.43.0-rancher1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                 20m (x4 over 21m)     kubelet            Created container controller
  Normal   Started                 20m (x4 over 21m)     kubelet            Started container controller
  Warning  BackOff                 4m57s (x76 over 21m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

Versions

k8s: 1.20.5

ingress: rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-0.43.0-rancher1